# How do I wait for a user to answer a question in discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

I am having problems in discord.py because when I ask a question and run the check whether the answer is valid, it scans the lack of messages and sends the error message I coded in straight away, which was supposed to happen only if they sent an invalid response.

```
if message.content.startswith('!examplecommand'):
    
  await message.channel.send("Example Question?")
  if message.content in Yes or if message.content in No:
     await message.channel.send('Example answer')
  else:
    await message.channel.send("Invalid response")
```

Can someone help me wait for a response before the check?

Edit: Thanks for the help, but the code does not seem to work.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.startswith("!examplecommand"):
    await message.channel.send("Example Question?")
    question_message.append(message)
    for msg in question_message: 
      if message.channel == question_message:
        if message.content() in Example_Group or message.content() in 
        Example_Group_1 or message.content() in Example_Group_2 or 
        message.content() in Example_Group_3: 
          await message.channel.send("Example Response")
        else:
          await message.channel.send('Invalid Response')
```

Comment: Ho yea, there is another little problem. In ```if message.channel == question_message:```
It should be ```if message.channel == msg.channel:``` because you need to check if it is the same channel but the statement checked if channel obj == msg obj. (question_message is the array that is holding the msgs so thats also why it didn't work)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this piece of code is in on_message().
If you meant that the answer will be on a separate message so:
The thing with the discord on_message() is that it makes the function run when a message is sent, so trying to wait for a message like that wont work because the message.content will still be- `!examplecommand`.
What you need to do is make a way to scan for a future message as your answer.
This can be done like:

```
#outside on_message
asked_question = False 
question_message = []
# these two variables will hold your message from the command and if there was a question asked.
----
#inside on_message
if message.content.startswith('!examplecommand'):
     await message.channel.send("Example Question?")
     asked_question = True
     question_message = message
elif asked_question and message.channel == question_message :
     if message.content.lower() == "yes" or message.content.lower() == "no":
     #lower meant so there wont be any capitalizing problems
        await message.channel.send('Example answer')
     else:
        await message.channel.send("Invalid response")
```

The problem with this as well is that someone can "!examplecommand" on another channel or another server and the outer variables will change again, so the first "!examplecommand" that was sent wont be answered.
If you really want to have people send more than one "!examplecommand" you will probably need something like a list that will hold all of the messages like this:

```
#outside on_message
question_message = []
----------------
#inside on_message
if message.content.startswith('!examplecommand'):
     await message.channel.send("Example Question?")
     question_message.append(message)
for msg in question_message: #this wont run if there aren't messages in question_message
     if message.channel == msg.channel :
        if message.content.lower() == "yes" or message.content.lower() == "no": 
        #lower meant so there wont be any capitalizing problems
           await message.channel.send('Example answer')
        else:
           await message.channel.send("Invalid response")
```

Because of this you can probably make !examplecommand a separate command than put it in on_masseges() as well.

Comment: So do you put anything from the first block of code into the code? Because it doesn't seem to work with only the second

Comment: There was a problem in line of the if statements becuase you cant do ```if [statement] or if[statement]``` , you need to change it to ```if [statement] or [statement]```.   I fixed the second block if you wanna try to copy it again. If there is another error tell me

Comment: Thank you for helping! I already fixed the `or if` thing on my own, but it still doesn't seem to work. I'm pretty sure I did everything right, except that instead of words, I used groups of words. I thought that might be the error, but when I replaced the groups with normal words in the same way you did, and even when I tried to run your exact code, it still didn't seem to work. It asked `Example Question?` after `!examplecommand` ,but didn't run the check and never returned any response. Code is too long to attach in a comment so I will update the question..

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved easily using the `wait_for` method in the commands extension

```py
@client.command()
async def examplecommand(ctx):
    await message.channel.send("Example Question?")
    
    def check(msg):
        return msg.author.id == ctx.author.id and msg.channel.id == ctx.channel.id

    answermsg = await client.wait_for('message', check = check)

    if "yes" in answermsg.content.lower() or "no" in answermsg.content.lower():
        await ctx.send("example answer")

    else:
        await ctx.send("Invalid response")
```

As you can see, using `on_message` event to achieve that is simply not needed, also you should start using commands extension if you already haven't.

For more information, here's [the documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for).